# How can we redirect to same view without data loss

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two textbox on same view on project when I first time load we provide value on textbox from controller using model.name its show in view than i click on button another textbox show other value model.age but the model.name value is remove I want both the values in textbox.

```
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers {
  public class HomeController: Controller {
    // GET: Home

    Class1 cs = new Class1();
    public ActionResult Index() {
      if (TempData["A"] == null) {
        cs.name = "hi";
        TempData["A"] = "B";
      }
      return View(cs);
    }

    public ActionResult A() {
      cs.age = "hello";
      //return RedirectToAction("Index",cs);
      return View("Index", cs);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just make your variable/object static to retain values.

```
static Class1 cs = new Class1();
```

Comment: Making Class1 static will give the same values to all visitors.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home

    Class1 cs = new Class1();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if(TempData["A"]==null)
        {

            cs.name = "hi";
            TempData["A"] = "B";
        }

        return View(cs);
    }

    public ActionResult A(string name)
    {
       cs.age ="hello";
       cs.name = name;
       return View("Index", cs);

    }


    }
}
```